# Solving the diffusion/heat equation for a randomly distributed set of points in 3D

Tags: finite-volume, diffusion, unstructured-mesh, heat-transfer

In this problem I am trying to solve, I have a messy set of points distributed in 3D space, each with a defined temperature. If I would want to calculate the heat transfer scenario in this system, how would you recommend me an approach (numerically and with each computational tool)? I thought about triangulating the points and using a unstructured grid Finite Volume Method. Considering the maths around this is a bit harder than that of a structured grid, I assumed the possibility of interpolating the unstructured grid into a structured grid, solving the discretized diffusion model and then interpolating back to the unstructured grid.

Comment: What do you mean by "calculate the heat transfer scenario"?

Comment: Solving the transient heat equation

Comment: What I understand from your first sentence is that you already knew the temperature at the points.

Comment: Yes, but I want to calculate the temperature field (at each point) in the next instant in time considering thermal diffusion.

Comment: But we don't know how heat is transferred. Are the points connected by little rods that transport heat? Are the points part of a homogenous medium? An imhomogenous medium? If it is part of a homogenous medium, what do you know about the initial temperature *between* points? Without saying what you want to do, i.e., what the exact model is, there is no correct answer to your question.

Comment: The points are discrete particles. But I figured I could try assuming a homogeneous medium with a smooth temperature distribution, letting the temperature of each particle be a sample of that distribution, i.e. the temperature between the points is given by interpolation. I am not sure the validity of this model, but that is how I am trying to approach it currently.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a cloud of points and you don't want to use mesh-based methods like FEM or FVM, a possibility is to use a mesh-free method like the Finite Point Method. For instance, you could have a look at this article:

[Tatari, M., Kamranian, M., & Dehghan, M. (2011). The finite point method for the p-Laplace equation. Computational Mechanics, 48(6), 689-697.](https://doi.org/10.1007/s00466-011-0613-6)

There are many other [mesh-free methods](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Meshfree_methods), Finite Point Method is only one of them.